# Excel graphs x-axis

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have a series on data I'm plotting on a graph in excel. I want the x-axis to be dates, with the first date starting on 17 October 2012, the next date being 31 December 2012 and from there on the dates being 31 December every year. Is it possible to do this? It only allows me to have annual spacing?

Answer (score 0):

select the x-Axis and press ctrl+1 to fromat the axis, format the x-axis as text type. only with that option you can skip dates, or you can also format the dataset as text...

[image]